# Application [AWS CLI] Command shortcuts are not working globally

Tags: command-line, aws

I just installed *AWS CLI* on a few servers with Ubuntu 14 on. The last server I installed it on, cannot access the *AWS CLI* from the terminal and run commands.

This does not work:

```
aws --version
```

You need to do this:

```
/home/user/.local/lib/aws/bin/aws --version
```

How can I make `aws --version` work in the same manner it does on all the other servers?

Comment: It's probably your PATH variable, check it on your other servers and see if it matches. If not add `/home/user/.local/lib/aws/bin/` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PATH Variables needed to be added.

```
cd ~

vi .profile
```

Append: `:/home/user/.local/lib/aws/bin/` Behind: `PATH=":$HOME/bin`

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:/home/user/.local/lib/aws/bin/"
fi
```

> aws --version